# Effect of #include inside C++ enums

Tags: c++

```
enum CMD 

    {
        CMD_none,
        #define A(x)    CMD_##x,
        #include "cmd.h"
    };
```

I encountered the above while going through a [github repository](https://github.com/rcedgar/syncmer/blob/38c67e858143b12ea44817d581607703738aabd0/myutils.h#L449).
Can someone tell me what the above code does? I do not understand the effect of `#include` inside `enum`. The official documentation also does not tell anything about such cases.

Comment: The effect of an `#include` inside an enum is the same as outside the enum:  the contents of the file are expanded *in situ*.  Whether the result is syntactically or semantically useful is further along the compiling toolchain pipeline.

Comment: The effect won't change: It pastes the contents of specified file to where `#include` is written.

Comment: At a guess `stdio.h` has already been included so fortunately it's include guards stop this from breaking horribly. I imagine this was added by mistake

Comment: @AlanBirtles The include is not `<stdio.h>` but `"stdio.h"`, so it may be an original header file with confusing name.

Comment: This looks like an x-macro, but it's weird to have `stdio.h` and also weird for it to be included as `"stdio.h"` rather than `<stdio.h>` or `<cstdio>` in C++

Comment: `while going through a github repository` So why not post a link to it? Are you sure the header was named "stdio"?

Comment: Which github repo? I suspect the code is trying to implement some type of automatic enum generation, but would need to see more.

Comment: For reference - you can find the file at https://github.com/rcedgar/syncmer/blob/master/myutils.h line 449

Comment: Also actually it was "cmds.h" not "stdio.h" . I imagined effect of including any header file would be same so I modified it to make the question context independent

Comment: Also can someone tell me why was this done? Since it is so unusual to see I'm assuming there must be other 'standard' workaround maybe?

Comment: [cmds.h](https://github.com/rcedgar/syncmer/blob/master/cmds.h) seems to be a list of enum names, this file is included twice with different `#define`s to avoid repeating the list of names

Comment: ` #include "stdio.h"` is a typo in the question. The linked code includes a different file - probably a table of enumerator values for which #define A(x)    CMD_##x, is relevant.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @Bathsheba I have corrected the mistake in question.Actually, I failed to realize how important the context would actually be in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone tell me what the above code does?
>
> ```
> enum CMD 
>
>     {
> ```

This is a declaration of an enum by the name `CMD`.

> ```
> CMD_none,
> ```

This is the first enumerator. Its name is `CMD_none` and the value is 0.

> ```
> #define A(x)    CMD_##x,
> ```

This is a pre-processor macro definition.

> ```
> #include "stdio.h"
> ```
>
> I do not understand the effect of #include inside enum.

The effect of #include is to include the content of the file into the source file that contains the #include directive.

It can be reasonable - although likely obfuscatory - if the included file contains valid list of enumerators. `"stdio.h"`, if it resolves to the standard header, does not contain a valid list of enumerators, and thus it makes no sense to write this. I suspect that it has been written by mistake.

Comment: question has s/studio/cmds.h, which explains a lot